# Preserving original index when using pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe that I'm wanting to groupby year and return the max value (but keep the index values as they are here):

```
import pandas as pd

dct = {
"date": ["2019-01-01", "2019-04-1", "2020-01-01"],
"high": [100, 150, 100],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
df.set_index("date",inplace=True)
df.index = [pd.Timestamp(i) for i in df.index]
df.index.name = "date" 

# date         high
# 2019-01-01   100
# 2019-04-01   150
# 2020-01-01   100
```

When using pandas groupby, Im able to group them by year, but not get the date that I want:

```
func = lambda x: x.year
df["high"].groupby(func).max()

# date    high
# 2019    150
# 2020    100
```

My desired output is to use pandas groupby and get:

```
 # NOTE : the date index is like the original

 # date         high
 # 2019-04-01   150
 # 2020-01-01   100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort_values` then do `groupby` with `tail`

```
df.sort_values('high').groupby(df.index.year).tail(1)
            high
date            
2020-01-01   100
2019-04-01   150
```

When you doing the `df["high"].groupby(func).max()`, it is [series groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) not dataframe groupby , so the output will not carry over the dataframe index

Comment: why does this work? what does the groupby object represent?

Comment: @thomas.mac when you func = lambda x: x.year
df["high"].groupby(func).max(), you pass serise groupby not dataframe groupby , so it will not carry over the dataframe index

Comment: @thomas.mac https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html

Answer (score 1):

Another way is use `idxmax` and `loc` access:

```
df.loc[df.groupby(df.index.year).high.idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
            high
date            
2019-04-01   150
2020-01-01   100
```

Answer (score 0):

You also could use `nlargest` and `droplevel`

```
func = lambda x: x.year

df["high"].groupby(func).nlargest(1).droplevel(0)

Out[7]:
date
2019-04-01    150
2020-01-01    100
Name: high, dtype: int64
```